# Python lists and iterables

Tags: python

in Python 3.2 How do I alter items in a list with a function and return the result of the function over the item and the item itself before altering? 10x

```
def some(func,seq):
    # What to do here?
```

Comment: You have a list. And a function. And what do you want to do?

Answer (score 3):

Something like

```
def func(my_func,seq):
    return seq, [my_func(n) for n in seq]
```

or

```
def func(my_func,seq):
    return [(my_func(n),n) for n in seq]
```

... your description is not very clear in that regard.

What's being used here is a *list comprehension*. `my_func` is called once for every element in `seq` and should return the function value for this element.

Comment: Aren't `map(lambda x: f(x), seq)` or `map(lambda x: (f(x), x), seq)` much better?

Comment: No. List comprehenshions are preferred way of doing this things.

Comment: @khachik: For the first case, `map(f, seq)` is better than your lambda. But note that `map` returns an iterable, not a list. And as pajton mentioned, list comprehension is preferred over lambdas.

Comment: Please, check your code. The parameter func should be my_function.

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. I have the following: def someFunc(func, seq). someFunc should return a dictionary, where the keys are the results of the func over the seq and the values should be a lists containing the elemenst on which the func returned the value. Maybe that`s not clear but this is the best i can do. 10x